# Rangers can attack twice from beginning even without the melee combat style?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

It's a little confusing, can the ranger attack 2 times with melee weapons, even if it has "fighting style" in bow and arrow?

I hope you can help me with that.

Comment: It's kinda unclear of what you're asking here; do you think you can link to the rules causing your confusion in the SRD?

Answer (score 13):

In short, yes: an Archery Ranger can get multiple melee attacks the same way anyone else can get multiple attacks. He simply doesn’t get any from his special class features.

Specifically, *anyone* with Base Attack Bonus +6 can attack twice with a weapon during a full-round attack. Rangers get BAB +6 at 6th level, since they get a BAB equal to their level. A Ranger who chooses the Archery Combat Style does not gain any special benefits in this regard, but he can still do it.

Further, *anyone* with two weapons may choose to use the Two-Weapon Fighting combat option to attack once with each weapon during a full-round attack. There are massive penalties if you do this without the Two-Weapon Fighting feat, which the Ranger’s Dual-Wielding Combat Style grants as a bonus feat, but you *can* still do it.

And you can always take that feat on your own; everyone gains a feat at 1st level, and then every 3rd level (so 1, 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, and 18). Humans gain another bonus feat at 1st. So a Ranger who chooses the Archery Combat Style can still *also* have Two-Weapon Fighting, he just has to take it normally like everyone else; his class doesn't help.

But ordinarily you choose one focus (dual-wielding or archery) and stay with it. Switching between a pair of weapons and a bow is cumbersome. If you really wanted to be both, it probably makes the most sense to focus on throwing weapons rather than actual archery (the Archery Combat Style feats still apply to thrown weapons), so you can do melee or ranged as you like. You will probably want to multiclass with Fighter for a couple of levels because you will need a *ton* of feats, though, and some Rogue levels for Sneak Attack would help.

Also, note that (almost) *all* extra attacks, including those from high BAB and from Two-Weapon Fighting, require a full-round attack action. A full-round action is instead of your usual move and standard actions, which means you typically cannot move *and* full-round attack. If you use your move action, then you can only use a standard action to attack, which is only a single attack. You may, however, take a “five-foot step” as a free action instead of moving, allowing you to attack with the full-round action. And things like Manyshot allow multiple attacks as a standard action. But usually the five-foot step is the only movement you can manage while still maintaining your extra attacks.

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to know ... from the beginning and creation of characters (any) can attack 2 times, but heavily penalized, everyone gets at level 6 a second attack because of its advance.

The rangers only gain skills class, as if they won feats that improve their combat skills.

Thanks, the answers were very complete.
Greetings.

Comment: @Daniel Not everyone gets BAB +6 at 6th level: bards, clerics, druids, monks, and rogues get it at 8th level, and sorcerers and wizards get it at 12th level. Rangers gain bonus feats in addition to the feats everyone can get, which can include Two-Weapon Fighting, but if they choose Archery, they can still take Two-Weapon Fighting normally.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, any character regardless of class or selection of class features can get multiple attacks if they use two weapons or a double weapon like a quarterstaff. However there are penalties to hit based upon feats and the type of weapons which can be found here: http://www.d20srd.org/srd/combat/specialAttacks.htm#twoWeaponFighting.

The choice of two weapon fighting for a ranger just gives the the Two Weapon Fighting feat for free. The feat just makes it easier to fight with two weapons.